# Use value of knockout observable within table data to apply CSS class

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I'm struggling to get the [KO CSS binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) to work. `portAvailable` is an observable boolean present in each device in `$root.devices`. When a device port is unavailable, `portAvailable` is `false`, and the CSS class `text-warning` should be added to the `td` element for the device.

The `ifnot` data bind below it does work, so there's something wrong with how I'm trying to apply the CSS data bind, not the observable itself.

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center">{{ _('Name') }}</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">{{ _('Port') }}</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="sortable: { data: $root.devices, options: { cancel: '.unsortable', handle: '.moveDevice', axis:'y'} }">
    <tr>
        <td><span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
        <td data-bind="css: {'text-warning': portAvailable == false}">
            <span data-bind="text: port"></span>
            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" title="{{ _('Port currently unavailable') }}" data-bind="ifnot: portAvailable"></i>
        </td>
        <td style="text-align:right">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-mini moveDevice"><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `portAvailable` is an observable. You need to unwrap it in the expression:

```
<td data-bind="css: {'text-warning': portAvailable() === false}">
```

The reason the `ifnot` binding does work is because, like all bindings, if all they receive is an observable, it will unwrap the observable for you if necessary.

Comment: That works, thanks! Turns out the `ifnot` was also not working, but your answer works there too.